# PHP Facebook SDK publish posts in Fan Page

Tags: php, facebook

I have created an account in Facebook Developers, and I've generated the token with long live (never expire). I've correctly published the post with my script PHP. The problem is that the only person who can read it is me. It isn't published in my Fan Page. It is neider published in my personal profile. It is in an intermediate point between my personal profile and my Fan Page.

The app created in Facebook Developers is active and published. I just want to publish my blog posts in my Fan Page.

The permissions configured in my Access Token are: manage_pages and publish_actions. I have in another platform and it works perfectly. Can you give me any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using your facebook account's token to post? or the facebook page's one?

Comment: I'm not sure. When debug my token appears the name of my FanPage. Because of that I think the token is the token FanPage.

Comment: Can you share the screentshot of the post and code you've used

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not made public yet (check app dashboard, Status and Review tab, “Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”) – as long as it is not set live, all content created through it will only be visible to you.

You always need to do this for each api key.

Comment: This check is in green state. I'm sure that this button is active

Comment: Well, that situation of posts made by api being private only, is exactly what happens when the api is not available to general public. In the past, I also though it was enabled everywhere, but in the end it wasn't... If later I can get more info on this, I'll let you know.